# Deploy a ClickOnce application without signing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, clickonce

I have pretty clear how signing works in a ClickOnce application, but in an intranet scenario I don't get the difference between adding a test certificate or not signing the manifest at all.

Why should I sign it? In both cases, I will get the same "Unknow publisher" and the application works fine, and in the first case I will just have an expired certificate in one year.

Comment: Click Once helps, but has lots of problems. The guys at Github made Shimmer (https://github.com/github/shimmer) which hopefully should make deployable & updatable apps less painful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a self-issued certificate (via Visual Studio). When you use a self-issued certificate, and the user decides to accept these credentials, then in the future you can do a rebuild/deploy with the same sef-issued certificate. The user will get an auto-update.

Otherwise, the user has to uninstall the old one, reinstall the new one. So, if you never do any updates, then there won't be any difference to the user.

Comment: I have just checked and my application without any certificate auto-update correctly when a new version is presente like when it was signed

Comment: The difference is that a signed app has an additional layer of security to reduce the risk of someone else replacing your program with something malicious (unless they steal your key).  Think about how a co-worker/contractor/hacker could put a new version of your program into the click-once folder and nobody might know the difference.  Smaller companies don't have as much to worry about, but mid-to-large companies worry about that kind of thing a lot.

Comment: This is definitely true but if I am in a intranet scenario where I don't have to bother about security would there be any difference?

Comment: If you don't sign it, you can update just fine. You generally want to use a certificate; it hashes the manifest and makes it more difficult for someone to hijack your application, as noted by tgolisch. In an intranet scenario, it's okay to not sign your application; it's more important if you're publishing publicly. It doesn't cost you anything, so why wouldn't you sign it? If in an enterprise, you can usually get a "real" cert from the network guys that will get rid of "unknown publisher".